# Gnuplot BibTeX citation

Tags: gnuplot, bibtex

OK, this is not a proper programming question, but maybe the answer will help others. I've been trying to find a suitable BibTeX entry for `gnuplot`, to include in a scientific publication. I just don't want to cite any guide book, but the actual software.

Does anyone have an idea, or ever used that? I was hoping to find something similar to the `citation()` command in `R`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prescribed form to cite `Gnuplot` so there is no command like `cite()`. But earlier, I have also met the problem and find a so-so standard **biblatex** enytry form:

```
@Misc{ gnuplot ,                    
author={ Thomas Williams and Colin Kelley and {many others} },                
title={ Gnuplot 4.6: an interactive plotting program },                    
month={ April },                    
year={ 2013 },                    
howpublished={ \url{http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/} }                    
}
```

Comment: This BibTeX entry should work for me as well. I'll just have to adjust the version. Thanks!