# bibTeX citation for stackoverflow

Tags: bibtex

(I am not sure if this question belongs to the meta website or not, but here we go)

I want to add stackoverflow to the bibliography of a research paper I am writing, and wonder if there is any bibTeX code to do so. I already did that for [gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955902/gnuplot-bibtex-citation)

I searched online, but in most cases the citation goes to a specific thread. In this case, I want to acknowledge SO as a whole, and add a proper citation, probably to the website itself. Hopefully somebody already did this in the past?

As an example, below are the codes I use for R and gnuplot:

```
@Manual{rproject,
          title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
         author = {{R Core Team}},
   organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
        address = {Vienna, Austria},
           year = {2015},
            url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
}



@MISC{gnuplot,
      author = {Thomas Williams and Colin Kelley and {many others}},
       title = {Gnuplot 5.0: an interactive plotting program},
       month = {June},
        year = {2015},
howpublished = {\href{http://www.gnuplot.info/}{http://www.gnuplot.info/}}
}
```

I know that both are software, not website resources, but maybe something along those lines would work. Any feedback is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: it will be helpful to show your code.

Comment: I don't have a code for that yet. I'll add the citation to R I have, and I'll probably use that if there is no other obvious alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize this question never got answered. The solution I found was to acknowledge the SO website in the LaTeX code with the following:

```
This research has made use of the online Q\&A platform {\texttt{stackoverflow}}
(\href{http://stackoverflow.com/}{http://stackoverflow.com/}).
```

Hope it helps somebody in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for my paper I am using the following citation:

```
@misc{stackoverflow, 
   url={https://stackoverflow.com/},
   title={Stack overflow},
   year={2008}
}
```

I hope it helps!